# Java PipedInputStream available() method return value

Tags: java, inputstream, pipe

I am trying to write a piece of unblocking code to  read from a [`PipedInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html). It basically checks if there is anything to be read before calling the blocking read API:

```
int n = 0;
if ((n = pipedInputStream_.available()) > 0) {
     pipedInputStream_.read(...)
}
```

Reading through the [java API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) I cant tell for sure what that check should be, since the possible values are zero (implies no data, or closed/broken stream) or greater than zero . So how can the caller know if there is anything to be read at all?

> "Returns the number of bytes that can be read from this input stream without blocking, or 0 if this input stream has been closed by invoking its close() method, or if the pipe is unconnected, or broken."

Looking at the source it seems like the only values are zero or greater than zero.

```
public synchronized int available() throws IOException {
    if(in < 0)
        return 0;
    else if(in == out)
        return buffer.length;
    else if (in > out)
        return in - out;
    else
        return in + buffer.length - out;
}
```

Comment: Zero does not imply a closed or broken stream. Zero or greater than zero are the only permissible results per specification.

Comment: Can you clarify why you say zero does not imply closed or broken stream? Please look at seh's explanation which I agree with. The Java doc also says that:

"Returns:
the number of bytes that can be read from this input stream without blocking, or 0 if this input stream has been closed by invoking its close() method, or if the pipe is unconnected, or broken."

Comment: You misunderstood. Zero implies *either* there is no data to be read without blocking *or* the stream has been closed *or* the pipe is unconnected *or* the pipe is broken. It doesn't imply just *one* of those conditions.

Comment: Sure. The appendage cleared the confusion caused by first statement in your earlier response.

Comment: The confusion here is contained in your statement. I've edited it for you.

Comment: I see what caused the confusion now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `available()` returns zero, there are no bytes available to read at present. Per the documentation you quote, that can be so for several reasons:

- The pipe was closed.
- The pipe is broken.
- All the previously-available input (if any) was already consumed.

A zero return value from `available()` *might* imply that an error had occurred, implying that you will never be able to read any more data through the pipe in the future, but you can't tell for sure here, because zero might be indicating that third condition above, where blocking on `InputStream#read()` might eventually yield more data that the corresponding `OutputStream` side will push through the pipe.

I don't see that it's possible to poll a `PipedInputStream` with `available()` until more data becomes available, because you'll never be able to distinguish the terminal cases above (the first and the second) from the reader being more hungry than the writer. Like so many stream interfaces, here too you have to *try to consume and be ready to fail*. That's the trap; `InputStream#read()` will block, but not until you commit to blocking on an attempt to read will you be able to discern that no more input is coming.

It is not feasible to base your consuming actions on `available()`. If it returns a positive number, there's *something* to be read, but of course even what is available now might not be "enough" to satisfy your consumer. You will find your application easier to manage if you commit a thread to consuming the `InputStream` in blocking fashion and skip the polling with `available()`. Let `InputStream#read()` be your sole oracle here.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, after looking at rest of PipedInputStream code, particularly the implementation/use of Circular buffer I see the third terminal condition to also be one of reasons for zero.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a filter to intercept slow connections where I need to close DB connections ASAP so I initially used Java pipes but when looked closer at their implementation, it is all synchronized so I ended up creating my own QueueInputStream using a small buffer and Blocking queue to put the buffer in the queue once was full, it is lock free except when for the lock conditions used at LinkedBlockingQueue which with the aid of the small buffer it should be cheap, this class is only intended to be used for a single producer and consumer per instance:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class QueueOutputStream extends OutputStream
{
  private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE=1024;
  private static final byte[] END_SIGNAL=new byte[]{-1};

  private final BlockingQueue<byte[]> queue=new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
  private final byte[] buffer;

  private boolean closed=false;
  private int count=0;

  public QueueOutputStream()
  {
    this(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
  }

  public QueueOutputStream(final int bufferSize)
  {
    if(bufferSize<=0){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer size <= 0");
    }
    this.buffer=new byte[bufferSize];
  }

  private synchronized void flushBuffer()
  {
    if(count>0){
      final byte[] copy=new byte[count];
      System.arraycopy(buffer,0,copy,0,count);
      queue.offer(copy);
      count=0;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void write(final int b) throws IOException
  {
    if(closed){
      throw new IllegalStateException("Stream is closed");
    }
    if(count>=buffer.length){
      flushBuffer();
    }
    buffer[count++]=(byte)b;
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void close() throws IOException
  {
    flushBuffer();
    queue.offer(END_SIGNAL);
    closed=true;
  }

  public Future<Void> asyncSendToOutputStream(final ExecutorService executor, final OutputStream outputStream)
  {
    return executor.submit(
            new Callable<Void>()
            {
              @Override
              public Void call() throws Exception
              {
                try{
                  byte[] buffer=queue.take();
                  while(buffer!=END_SIGNAL){
                    outputStream.write(buffer);
                    buffer=queue.take();
                  }
                  outputStream.flush();
                } catch(Exception e){
                  close();
                  throw e;
                } finally{
                  outputStream.close();
                }
                return null;
              }
            }
    );
  }

}
```